# Compare three big matrices - Best way to get a meaningful and easy to understand indicator of the relation between the matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 3 matrices (55000x3 double) and want to compare them. 
I'm taking the arithmetic mean of the value of each position and want to provide in addition an indicator how the three matrices correlate.

The values in one position of the matrices are for example:

- Matrix1 pos(1:1): 3.679
- Matrix2 pos(1:1): 3.721
- Matrix3 pos(1:1): 3.554

As I cannot just give the standard deviation for each value because it would be to much information I'm looking for a way to give a meaningful statement for the correlation without having to much information.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Make it a `55000x3x3` double, i.e. 3D and take the mean across the third dimension.

Comment: I would suggest looking at principle component analysis (PCA) or single value decomposition (SVD).  Basically it boils down to eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrices.  PCA includes variance and co-variance matrices which sounds useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the [correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient). You can reshape each of your matrices into a vector (using `(:)`), and then compute the correlation coefficient for each pair of vectors (originally matrices) using [`corrcoef`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html).

For example, let:

```
Matrix1 =    [ 1   2;   3   4;   5   6   ];
Matrix2 = -2*[ 1   2;   3   4;   5   6   ];
Matrix3 =    [ 1.1 2.3; 3.4 4.1; 4.9 6.3 ];
```

Then

```
C = corrcoef([Matrix1(:) Matrix2(:) Matrix3(:)]);
```

gives

```
C =
    1.0000   -1.0000    0.9952
   -1.0000    1.0000   -0.9952
    0.9952   -0.9952    1.0000
```

This tells you that, in this case,

- Each of the three matrices is totally correlated with itself (`C(1,1)`, `C(2,2)` and `C(3,3)` equal `1`). This is obvious.
- Matrices 1 and 2 have correlation coefficient `C(1,2)` equal to `-1`. This was expected, because matrix 2 is a negative multiple of matrix 1.
- Matrices 1 and 3 are highly correlated (`C(1,3)` is `0.9952`). This is because matrix 3 was defined as matrix 1 with some random "noise".
- Matrices 2 and 3 are also highly correlated but with negative sign (`C(2,3)` is `-0.9952`), as should be clear from the above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried representing your data using boxplot?

boxplot(([data(:,1); data(:,2); data(:,3)])');

Comment: Not what I'm looking for.I know how my values are roughly distributed but I need a statistical indicator to prove the relation